# Is the var token necessary to signal variable declaration?

Tags: language-agnostic, language-design, parsing

When creating a variable `foo`, Python lets you just write `foo = bar`. However many languages, like C# or JavaScript, require additional syntax like `var foo = bar` or `foo := bar` to signal the same thing.
Is there a reason why C#/JS require explicitly differentiating a declaration from assignment?

I can imagine that a parser, upon reading `foo = bar`, has to decide whether the `=` means declaration or assignment. But that's easy - just check if `foo` was declared earlier. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I'm confused. You ask whether whether it is necessary, and in the very same paragraph you mention a language where it isn't.

Comment: Thank you, I have edited the question to better reflect what I mean. Hopefully this clears things up.

Answer (score 10):

> But that's easy - just check if foo was declared earlier

And therein lies your problem.

In languages like Javascript, it's all too easy to "shadow" a variable that you've already defined earlier without knowing it, and now you've got strange behavior that you can't explain.  The problem is exacerbated in Javascript because all variables not otherwise sequestered in a function live in the global namespace, where they are easily stomped on by rogue code.

C# eliminates this problem by defining a strict set of rules governing how variables can be declared and when.  Part of these rules is having syntax that distinguishes declaration from assignment (i.e. the `var` keyword), and disallowing the reuse of variable names that appear in the enclosing scope.

Comment: Sadly, I'm barely literate in JS, so that doesn't help much. But I've never had problems with "stomping" or shadowing variables in Python - so maybe that's just a JS problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19902127

Comment: From what I understand, the only actual problem there was an IDE misunderstanding the asker's intention. I'd be grateful if you could explain what you meant.

Comment: @uryga It isn't the IDE misinterpreting you, it's abiding by the rules of the language. Basically, JS is a good example because it allows you to declare or overwrite variables without explicit syntax, but also has some confusing scoping rules, so it may not be obvious that you've overwritten something that you shouldn't have. If the declaration was explicit, accidental shadows and overwrites would yield errors. You may have not experienced such a situation yet, but as projects become bigger, and namespace more polluted, it becomes more and more likely a scenario.

Comment: @uryga The language rules are in place to reduce the likelihood of accidents, which although limiting in the short term become very beneficial when debugging massive amounts of code since it limits where the mistakes could have happened, limiting where you need to look. I read an article where a highly hyped site was broken in hard to trace ways because they accidentally declared a variable as global, and just constantly rewrote over it, leaking information. I'll link if I can find it.

Comment: Ok, I can see the benefit of safety. I've done things like accidentally reusing the same i in nested for loops, which, like you say, was not easy to trace. And that was a 200 line program... so I guess typing `var` isn't a big price to pay for preventing that entire class of bugs.

Comment: It's also worth noting that 'var' in C# is a comparatively recent addition. Previously, you would have to declare the Type of the variable - e.g. DateTime myDateTime = .... . This is useful as it shows the intended type of the variable, so it's harder to get your types mixed up. Sadly, 'var' only shows your intent to declare a variable that will have it's type resolved later. This is useful for anonymous types (and LINQ queries are probably why this was introduced. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb397696.aspx), but the overuse of this keyword is something I personally dislike.

Comment: @AndyBurns: It's probably overused [less than you think](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16881816/102937).  There's no reason to respecify the type when it is already clear from the context, and no one should ever have to write the signature for something like `List<Expression<Tleft, TRight, bool>>` twice on the same line.

Answer (score 3):

there are two distinct steps involved, "creating" a variable, and "assigning" a value.
Think of it like "building a house" and "renting a house".
the house may only be built once, but can be rented an infinite number of times.
Different languages handle it differently because some language designers think its a good idea to let a house be built whenever you get your first renter, and some want to ensure the house is built before attempting to rent it out.

Comment: ...and some language designers think it's a good idea to [only rent the house out to one person.](https://www.google.com/search?q=immutability&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a reason why C#/JS require explicitly differentiating a declaration from assignment?

There is, you don't want typos to declare new variables, you want them to not work.

For example, consider the following Python code:

```
someValue = 42
if someCondition:
    someVaule = 43;
```

This is clearly a bug caused by a typo, but Python does not prevent you from writing such code. C# does, to ensure typos don't become bugs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn more programming languages, there is much more than C# & Javascript & C++ & Python. So read Scott's  [Programming Language Pragmatics](https://www.cs.rochester.edu/%7Escott/pragmatics/) book & [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) (a very good introductory book that would teach you [Scheme](http://schemers.org/))

In particular, *variables* in Ocaml, Scheme, Common Lisp, Haskell are quite different than what you believe (or what they are in C++, C#, Javascript). Notice in particular that in Ocaml, variables introduced by some `let` binding *never vary*. And variables in [Prolog](http://www.learnprolognow.org/index.php) are also very different.

There is also the issue of typos on variables when typing code. I like languages and implementations where a typo (e.g. `fooo` instead of `foo`) gives immediately some diagnostics most of the time.

Comment: I started learning haskell a while back and I know how `let foo = bar` works. While `let` is nice because it indicates immutability, `var` seems superfluous to me, which is why I asked the question.  But I guess it has a benefit of a symmetry between `let` and `var` in languages that have both.

Comment: If you are designing your language you might have `var` playing a role similar to `let`; very crudely `var` has such a role in Javascript inside a function but the variable scope is the entire function block with `var` instead of a lexical scope with `let`